# PEP8 E226 recommendation

Tags: python, pep8

The [E226](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes) error code is about *"missing whitespace around arithmetic operator"*.

I use [Anaconda](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/)'s package in Sublime which will highlight as a PEP8 E226 violation for example this line:

```
hypot2 = x*x + y*y
```

But in [Guido's PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) that line is actually shown as an example of [recommended use](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations) of spaces within operators.

Question: which is the correct guideline? Always spaces around operators or just in some cases (as Guido's recommendation shows)?

Also: who decides what goes into PEP8? I would've thought Guido's recommendation would pretty much determine how that works.

Comment: Not sure what answer you're hoping for here... PEP 8 is PEP 8. Sublime's PEP 8 style checker is a different topic. Perhaps/obviously the implementer of that package has not implemented that particular rule exactly as described in the actual PEP 8 recommendation.

Comment: Sorry, I added my actual question to be more clear. I'd like to know which guideline is the correct one. The second question is a less important question.

Comment: Um, there is only one guideline in your question, what do you want us to choose from?

Comment: There's only one PEP 8, and if PEP 8 very explicitly says that you can do that, then that's the final word. If a particular style checker says something to the contrary, then it's not a 100% compliant PEP 8 checker.

Comment: I thought that there was a unique standardized implementation of PEP8 among all packages. It didn't occur to me that this was an issue with how this particular checker decided to mark E226.

Comment: To follow on from @deceze's comment, [Guido argues](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/issues/466)   that it isn't possible to have a 100% compliant PEP8 checker, because PEP8 is a style guide, not law.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The maintainers of the PEP8 tool decide what goes into it.

As you noticed, these do not always match the PEP8 style guide exactly. In this particular case, I don't know whether it's an oversite by the maintainers, or a deliberate decision. You'd have to ask them to find out, or you might find the answer in the commit history.

Guido recently asked the maintainers of pep8 and pep257 tools to rename them, to avoid this confusion.  [See this issue for example](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/issues/466). As a result, the tools are getting renamed to pycodestyle and pydocstyle, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Alasdair. I assumed things like this would've been settled long time ago.

Answer (score 5):

It says in PEP8:

> If operators with different priorities are used, **consider** adding whitespace around the operators with the lowest priority(ies). **Use your own judgment**; however, never use more than one space, and always have the same amount of whitespace on both sides of a binary operator. 
>   *(Emphasis is my own).*

In the listed example, `+` has a lower priority, so the BDFL elects to use whitespace around it and uses no whitespace around higher priority `*`.

Comment: Please explain downvotes. Can't learn anything from silence. :)

Comment: I upvoted and I have **never** understood downvotes with no explanations given. To me, they add nothing.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I imagine it would be because your response doesn't answer either of the OP's questions - i.e. Q1: is the pep8-text or the pep8-tool correct?, and Q2: who decides what goes into pep8?

Answer (score 0):

In this case that happened to me. We should have space always between numbers or variables and operations.

example:

```
a=b*4 wrong


a = b * 4  correct
```